# Adding Blur effect to view

Tags: ios, swift, uiblureffect

I have a view class which is used for showing a spinner with a blurred background view. I add this to another view during runtime and everything works fine. When I add this view to another ViewControllers view somehow the effect is not visible.The view does get added, I check it by setting the background colour to green and it is there.But the effect itself is not visible.I add the view in this manner
Ex:

```
 self.view.addSubview(self.loadingView)
 self.loadingView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size:self.view.frame.size)
```

.The Implementation is as below,

```
final class LoaderView: UIView {

    fileprivate let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)
    fileprivate let effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
    fileprivate let backgroundView = UIVisualEffectView(frame:.zero)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        spinner.startAnimating()

        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundView.effect = effect

        addSubview(backgroundView)
        addSubview(spinner)
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setSpinnerColor(color:UIColor){
        spinner.color = color
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        backgroundView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.height/5, height: self.bounds.height/5)
        backgroundView.center = CGPoint(x:self.bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: self.bounds.size.height / 2.0)
        backgroundView.clipsToBounds = true
        backgroundView.cornerRadius = 10
        spinner.center = center
    }
}
```

Comment: Debugging by sight, a few questions. (1) Does the `spinner` appear? (2) Have you tried sending other subviews of... `self.view` to the back? (3) The view controller that is loading this - can you let us know what place/override in it's lifecycle you are coding this? And for good measure, (4) can you give us a clearer idea of the view hierarchy you are (4a) expecting and (4b) seeing? I'm guessing - since you say you can *see* the view - that the issue is related to view hierarchy or when things get loaded.

Comment: I just solved the problem and man its was just ridiculous. The blur effect was set to light and well the first view I add it has a colourful background so it is visible. Well the rest of the Vİewcontrollers are all white. The blur was getting added it was just not visually visible because the effect was too light. I guess I needed sleep to realise this. Thanks for the debug suggestions.